# Customize Wordpress registration form

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, registration

I am using [Cimy User Extra Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/) plugin for extra fields in Wordpress registration but I would like to make it in two columns so users would not scroll since now I have to many fields. I have problem in how to implement it in code. When I am editing via Inspect element it looks like this

```
<form name="registerform" id="registerform" action="http://test.com/wp-login.php?action=register" method="post" style="
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -200px;
">
    <div style="float:left;width: 350px;" ;=""><p>
        <label for="user_login">Username<br>
        <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20"></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="user_email">E-mail<br>
        <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="input" value="" size="25"></label>
    </p>
<!--
    Start code from Cimy User Extra Fields 2.5.1
    Copyright (c) 2006-2013 Marco Cimmino
    http://www.marcocimmino.net/cimy-wordpress-plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/
-->
    <input type="hidden" name="cimy_post" value="1">
    <p id="cimy_uef_wp_p_field_1">
        <label for="cimy_uef_wp_1">Password</label><input type="password" name="cimy_uef_wp_PASSWORD" id="cimy_uef_wp_1" class="cimy_uef_input_27" value="" maxlength="100">
    </p>
    <p id="cimy_uef_wp_p_field_2">
        <label for="cimy_uef_wp_2">Password confirmation</label><input type="password" name="cimy_uef_wp_PASSWORD2" id="cimy_uef_wp_2" class="cimy_uef_input_27" value="" maxlength="100">
    </p></div>
    <div style="float:right;width: 350px;padding-left: 30px;" ;="">
    <p id="cimy_uef_wp_p_field_3">
        <label for="cimy_uef_wp_3">First name</label><input type="text" name="cimy_uef_wp_FIRSTNAME" id="cimy_uef_wp_3" class="cimy_uef_input_27" value="" maxlength="100">
    </p>
    <p id="cimy_uef_wp_p_field_4">
        <label for="cimy_uef_wp_4">Last name</label><input type="text" name="cimy_uef_wp_LASTNAME" id="cimy_uef_wp_4" class="cimy_uef_input_27" value="" maxlength="100">
    </p>
    <p id="cimy_uef_p_field_1">
        <label for="cimy_uef_1">Company</label><input type="text" name="cimy_uef_COMPANY" id="cimy_uef_1" class="cimy_uef_input_27" value="" maxlength="100">
    </p>
    <p id="cimy_uef_p_field_2">
        <label for="cimy_uef_2">Industry </label><select name="cimy_uef_INDUSTRY" id="cimy_uef_2" class="cimy_uef_input_27">
            <option value="Consulting">Consulting</option>
            <option value="Events and PR">Events and PR</option>
            <option value="Other industries">Other industries</option></select>
    </p>
    <br>
<!--
    End of code from Cimy User Extra Fields
-->
</div>
    <p id="reg_passmail">A password will be e-mailed to you.</p>
    <br class="clear">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="">
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Register"></p>
</form>
```

NOTE: I would like first div to open before `user_login` to close after `cimy_uef_wp_p_field_2`

Is there any way to make something like this since `user_login` is default wp-login.php field and `cimy_uef_wp_p_field_2` is Cimy User Extra Fields plugin field

Comment: This should really be asked on here - wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Okey,I posted also on wordpress.stackexchange.com , but it is more HTML CSS problem and on wordpress.stackexchange.com usually there is no answers :(

Comment: @AlexThomas at times I really confused with what type of wordpress questions we can posthere  and what to go for its sister wordpress exchange site..when user really looking for an answer in quick time